# Possible unintended reference comparison in combobox

Tags: c#

I have the following code which gives a warning in every if or else if

> Possible 
>   unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'

```
int delka = Convert.ToInt32(delka_numericUpDown1.Value);
if (delka_comboBox1.SelectedItem == "metr" &&
    delka_comboBox2.SelectedItem == "kilometr")
{
    delka_vysledek_label.Text = Convert.ToString(delka / 1000);
}
```

This doesn't appear to be a duplicate because I couldn't find solution to my specific issue in other questions.

Comment: The warning is telling you exactly what's going on. If there's some part you don't understand about it, how about asking an actual question about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SelectedItem - For gets this will return the actual **object** in the DataSource that is being displayed in the ComboBox.  For sets if the value exists in the DataSource, it will be selected, otherwise the operation will complete without an exception but won't actually do anything.

Try to parse the object returned by `SelectedItem` to `string` using `ToString()` method before comparing it with other strings ("metr" & "kilometr") in condition :

```
if (delka_comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "metr" && delka_comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "kilometr")
{
    delka_vysledek_label.Text = Convert.ToString(delka / 1000);
}
```

Like @Patrick mentioned in comment : `SelectedItem` can be null, so if you want to cover also this case you can use another cast method `(string)` e.g :

```
if ((string)delka_comboBox1.SelectedItem == "metr" && (string)delka_comboBox2.SelectedItem == "kilometr")
{
    delka_vysledek_label.Text = Convert.ToString(delka / 1000);
}
```

Comment: Beware of `.ToString()` if `SelectedItem` can be null

Comment: That true @Patrick, so in this case we have to add another condition ?

Comment: No, you just cast it instead; `(string)delka_comboBox1.SelectedItem == "metr"`

Answer (score 0):

SelectedItem returns an Object, but you are comparing it to a string ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx)).  To get rid of this warning, you just have to call the ToString method.

Instead of

```
delka = Convert.ToInt32(delka_numericUpDown1.Value);

    if (delka_comboBox1.SelectedItem == "metr" && delka_comboBox2.SelectedItem == "kilometr")
    {
        delka_vysledek_label.Text = Convert.ToString(delka / 1000);
    }
```

You would want to do

```
delka = Convert.ToInt32(delka_numericUpDown1.Value);

    if (delka_comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "metr" && delka_comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "kilometr")
    {
        delka_vysledek_label.Text = Convert.ToString(delka / 1000);
    }
```